# Set a form's designmode property via reflection

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection

I can create and show a form that is loaded from a dll file via reflection.
I want to trick the floating form into thinking it is in design mode. I think it should be possible to find a backing variable in the form somewhere and set it via reflection but I can't quite find it AND the code to set it. Can someone help me find a way to get the form to think it is in design mode?

I know the property is read-only but maybe there is an underlying field.

Comment: Have a look the references source, that will tell you about the underlaying field. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/Component.cs,9fcbc73b12981877

Answer (score 0):

From thehennyy's comment, I made a phony class to act as a site:

```
public class MySite : IServiceProvider, ISite
{
    public IComponent Component => null;
    public IContainer Container => null;
    public bool DesignMode => true;
    public string Name { get => ""; set => value = ""; }
    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then before the form is launched I set the Site property to an instance of this class:

```
form.Site = new MySite();
```

This does work to make the form believe it is in design mode when actually it is not.  Site is fortunately a public property.